# "Internal Salesforce.com Error" in Apex called by LWC, but only for non-sysadmin users

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, error, customsetting

I have this class, which has been used by a VisualForce page for a couple of years. It accesses a custom setting named Data_kwaliteit__c:

```
public class MainPageController {
...
    private Data_kwaliteit__c dataQualitySetting {
        get {
            if (dataQualitySetting == null) {
                dataQualitySetting = Data_kwaliteit__c.getAll().values()[0];
            }
            return dataQualitySetting;
        }
        set;
    }
...
}
```

When this class is used by a VisualForce page, it works for everybody. When it is used by a Lightning Web Component, it only works for sysadmins. For other users I see in the debug log: "Internal Salesforce.com Error", and it occurs at the line

```
dataQualitySetting = Data_kwaliteit__c.getAll().values()[0];
```

Is there some setting that is different between Lightning and Classic that concerns access to custom setting objects?

Comment: Does a user has an access to Custom Settings (via View Custom Settings permission), that was recently introduced? It might be a cause of it

Comment: @kurunve Not quite, but it is related, as I found out. You pointed me in a direction and it helped, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit was this critical update: Use with sharing for @AuraEnabled Apex Controllers with Implicit Sharing ([link](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_lc_apex_with_sharing_cruc.htm))

The Apex class that was called by the LWC and that called the Apex class that I mentioned in the question, did not have an explicit sharing clause. Which implies, because of the critical update, "with sharing". Which means that non-sysadmin users got an error, because they do not have access to custom setting objects.

I solved it by setting the sharing clause of the class called by the LWC to "without sharing". It is appropriate in this case.

The internal error is a bit sloppy by Salesforce, it should be clearer.